# fire (call) method, when scrollviewer scrolled to its end

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pagination, scrollviewer

after being googled a lot, finally i am going to ask this to you guys.
i'v created `scrollviewer`, which contains items(`listboxItems`) and these items fetching from the `webservices`. but at once only 5 items can fetched. so initially it'll be 5 items, then next 5(appended to the `scrollviewer`) and then next 5 and so on......

note:-here `listBoxitems` are used inside the `scrollviewer`, not the listbox

**data fetched from** `webservice` **also contains**--->

```
total items
numResults (current number of items fetched)
```

now suppose my method to fetch data is--->

```
getData(int nextResult)
{
      // some code to fetch the data
}
```

where nextResult is next item number(ex:- nextResult is 6, if requesting 2nd time)

but i am unable to write **the code to detect that the user scrolled the scrollviewer to the end & then a method to be called or fired, whatever say!**

i'v been badly confused among scrollviewer's `VerticalOffset`, `ExtentHeight`, `ViewportHeight`, `ScrollableHeight` etc, about to use them & calculate desired information to achieve above requirements.

so if anyone knows about the same or used ever scrollviwer, than please post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by registering new DependencyProperty ListVerticalOffset with appropriate event:

```
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListVerticalOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListVerticalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(OnListVerticalOffsetChanged));

        YourScrollViewer.Loaded += YourScrollViewer_Loaded;
    }

    void YourScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = new Binding
            {
                Source = YourScrollViewer,
                Path = new PropertyPath("VerticalOffset"),
                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
            };
        SetBinding(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, binding);
    }

    private void OnListVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var atBottom = YourScrollViewer.VerticalOffset >= YourScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
        if (atBottom) MessageBox.Show("End");
    }

    public readonly DependencyProperty ListVerticalOffsetProperty;

    public double ListVerticalOffset
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ListVerticalOffsetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
    }
```

May be this solution or it's realization is not optimal, but it's working for me.

Comment: Hi Lumen, your solution also works for me, however I have 2 listboxes on 1 panorama page, so I registered 2 versions of your code above, however the 2 listboxes are mixing the data they are getting, how can I link a dependency property with a listbox?