# Dependency properties getting mixed up?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, dependency-properties

I basically have a panorama control with 2 panorama items, which simply contains lists of different items. I followed the tutorial on windows phone to detect when the user has reached the end of the list, then display new items - [fire (call) method, when scrollviewer scrolled to its end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944410/fire-call-method-when-scrollviewer-scrolled-to-its-end),

however my problem is that I need this for both listboxes, so I did register 2 different dependency properties, but how can I "link" a dependency property with a specific listbox, because the two are getting mixed up.

thank you

listbox 1

```
  <ListBox Foreground="Black" 
                         x:Name="nuus"
                         Loaded="nuus_Loaded_1"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Story}"
                         SelectionChanged="nuus_SelectionChanged_1">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="105" Width="432">
                                <Image Width="115" Height="115" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                                <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="8,0,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                           Margin="10,0" 
                                           Foreground="Black"
                                           FontSize="20"/>

                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreationDate}" 
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                           Foreground="Black"
                                           Margin="10,-2,10,0" 
                                           FontSize="20"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper class with the same functionality extracted to be able to duplicate it more easily:

```
public class ScollViewerEndListener :FrameworkElement
{

    public event EventHandler EndOfScrollReached;

    private ScrollViewer scrollViewer;
    public ScollViewerEndListener()
    {

    }

    public void Init(ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
    {
        this.scrollViewer = scrollViewer;
        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Source = scrollViewer,
            Path = new PropertyPath("VerticalOffset"),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        };
        SetBinding(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, binding);
    }



    private void OnListVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var atBottom = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
        if (atBottom)
        {
            if (EndOfScrollReached != null)
            {
                EndOfScrollReached(this, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public readonly DependencyProperty ListVerticalOffsetProperty;

    public double ListVerticalOffset
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ListVerticalOffsetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

That you can just use in your file like this:

```
ScollViewerEndListener scrollListenerFirstListBox=new ScollViewerEndListener ();
ScollViewerEndListener scrollListenerSecondListBox=new ScollViewerEndListener ();
```

In constructor:

```
scrollListenerFirstListBox.EndOfScrollReached += scrollListenerFirstListBox_EndOfScrollReached;
scrollListenerSecondListBox.EndOfScrollReached += scrollListenerSecondListBox_EndOfScrollReached;
```

When first list box loaded:

```
 scrollListenerFirstListBox.Init(ScrollViewerFirstListBox);
```

When second list box loaded:

```
scrollListenerSecondListBox.Init(ScrollViewerSecondListBox);
```

Here is a function to get the scrollviewer from the ListBox:

```
public ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject parentElement)
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
            if (child is ScrollViewer)
            {
                return child as ScrollViewer;
            }
            else
            {
                child = GetScrollViewer(child);
                if (child != null)
                {
                    return child as ScrollViewer;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You should call this function in the Loaded even of the ListBox like this:

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewerListA=this.GetScrollViewer(ListA);
```

Just another thing to mention is that if what you are trying to do is to create a infinite scrolling, the recomended way to do it is to use the [windows phone toolkit](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx) LongListSelector and follow this [article](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx)

Comment: where do you get the ScrollViewerFirstListBox and ScrollViewerSecondListbox when the listboxes loads?

Comment: I have added what my first listbox looks like

Comment: Updated with a way to get the scrollviewer, also added an link to the recomended way to do infinite scrolling if it is what you are trying to do